# Heuristics for the A* using fewest hops

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, heuristics

I have a graph of nodes and I need to get from node a to node b. What is a good heuristic function (can be in pseudo code or anything) for getting from point A to point B. The information available is the adjacency of nodes and the distances between all nodes.

Comment: It's really hard to say without a context to the problem. But I'd guess, you always pick a well networked node (more the connections the better) before a poorly networked node. (again, its just an idea)

Comment: When you say "the distances between all nodes", do you mean a) the weights of all edges, b) the costs of the best paths between all paths, c) the numbers of edges in those paths, or d) something else?

Comment: I have a list of nodes and all their adjacencies plus the location of those nodes on a cartesian plane.

Comment: Yes. Euclidean Distance.

Comment: Actually I was suggesting Euclidean distance as the heuristic. That doesn't necessarily get you the fewest edges. For that you'd have to find the shortest path assuming all edge weights (distances) are 1, and that's not really a heuristic as much as an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the distances between all nodes, then that is the best heuristic you can have.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Dijkstra's algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: Not sure how this answer helps (at all) and why it was upvoted. The OP is asking for a **heuristic** für A*. He's alreading *using* Dijkstra.